p4merge open each window minimized when running a git diff/ merge
I'm running on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and have p4merge installed in version p4v-2024.3.2656785.
I'm using p4merge since years and I really like it, but recently it started to open all windows minimized and if you want to check the differences you have to maximize the window manually. If you are doing a diff/merge with multiple files, this is quite annoying.
Maybe this is related to the recent ubuntu upgrade 24.04 -> 24.04.1, but I think the issue started shortly before.
In the past it opened the first window minimized and after i maximized this window, it then remembered its state and open the following windows in maximized view.
In my .gitconfig the diff/merge command for p4merge looks like this:
[mergetool "p4m"]
  cmd = p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
  keepTemporaries = false
  trustExitCode = false
  keepBackup = false

[difftool "p4m"]
  cmd = p4merge $LOCAL $REMOTE

Any ideas how to fix this?
